# How do I print something that is chosen randomly from a list?

Tags: python, random

If I use `print(random.sample(My_List, k=2))` Python chooses two things from my list randomly.

How can I tell Python to print one of the two random things it picked for me?

For example:

```
print("My personal favorite from those two would be ..."
```

How do I print something that is chosen randomly from my list?

Comment: assign it to a variable before printing

Comment: You can use `random.choice()`.

Comment: No both incorrect , yall just saying how to make python choose an item from my list randomly

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to a variable and then use concatenation.

```
myList = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'black', 'orange']
x=random.sample(myList, k=2)
print('My favorite color is ' + x[1])
```

Output:

```
My favorite color is blue
```

If you want to pick something random from your random sample, include random.choice:

```
print('My favorite color is ' + random.choice(x))
```

Comment: not really what i was asking , that just shows me how to make python choose something randomly from my list

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This has Python choose from the list, assigns the choices to a new list, and then print off one of the elements from the list either by (a) you calling it explicitly, or (b) Python choosing one randomly to print. What is it that you're looking for? I guess I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
print(f"My personal favorite from those two would be ... {random.choice(random.sample(My_List, k=2))}")
```

Comment: With this kind of solution you don't need a `sample`.

Comment: Agreed. Just answering the question.

Comment: i tried doing that but it still doesnt work, there are seven items in My_List and i already set it up to make it choose 2 items randomly from that list, i tried your code and it did give me one random item from my list but not from the output that python gave me randomly